# Problemas com Backup por Batch e com Software específico

Tags: batch, backup

Tenho dois problemas com backups realizados de formas diferentes (são soluções distintas e independentes), o primeiro é um "batch" (arquivo BAT) e o segundo é com o software de backup da SEAGATE DASHBOARD (chamarei de SD para simplificar).

O backup é feito de algumas pastas previamente selecionadas da unidade C, que trato como "HD_Server".

No caso do backup feito pelo arquivo BAT, são três opções de unidades externas (tratadas como "HD_Externo"), E:, F: ou G: para receber os dados atualizados das pastas selecionadas anteriormente.

Assim, como o arquivo tem o nome de BACKUP.BAT, para fazer o backup de C: para o HD externo em F:, basta executar `BACKUP F:`

Coloquei o batch completo abaixo, mas somente com duas pastas para exemplo, Contas1 e Contas2 que se encontram em C: (C:\Contas1 e C:\Contas2, respectivamente).

**Observações**: é gerado um arquivo de LOG do backup, são copiados os dados alterados inclusive dos sub-diretórios e ao final do arquivo há as indicações das opções usadas nos comandos.

```
cls
echo off

cls
echo ##### BACKUP PARCIAL #####

rem %%%%%%%%%%% DEFINA A UNIDADE A COPIAR %%%%%%%%%%% 

set UNID=E:

rem Opções de unidades:  E:, F: ou G:

cls

echo.

echo   .---------------------------------------------------------------------------.
echo   : O BACKUP SERA FEITO NA UNIDADE %UNID%                                     :
echo   :                                                                           :
echo   :                 De HD_SERVER para %UNID%\HD_Externo                       :
echo   :                 ===================================                       :
echo   :                                                                           :
ECHO   :              ***** CONECTAR AO HD EXTERNO PRIMEIRO *****                  :
echo   :                                                                           :
ECHO   :     ***** A LISTA A SEGUIR MOSTRA O ULTIMO BACKUP COM OS TEMPOS *****     :
echo   :                                                                           :
echo   :                                                                           :
echo   :                                                                           :
ECHO   :           Tecle  ENTER  para iniciar ou  CTRL+C  para cancelar            :
ECHO   `---------------------------------------------------------------------------;
echo.

pause

cls

echo.
echo.
echo         ##############  ULTIMO BACKUP  ##############
echo.

type backup_nb.txt

echo.

pause

cls

copy backup_nb.txt backup_nb.ant

del backup_nb.txt

cls

echo. >>backup_nb.txt
echo          **************************************************************>>backup_nb.txt
echo. >>backup_nb.txt
echo De HD_Server para HD_Externo>>backup_nb.txt
echo. >>backup_nb.txt
echo **************************************************************>>backup_nb.txt
echo. >>backup_nb.txt
echo. >>backup_nb.txt
echo ### INICIO ###>>backup_nb.txt
date /T>>backup_nb.txt
time /T>>backup_nb.txt
echo. >>backup_nb.txt

echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                 * * * * *  I N I C I O  D O  B A C K U P  * * * * *
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
date /T
echo.
time /T

echo.

echo **************************************************************
echo **************************************************************>>backup_nb.txt
echo C,Contas1
echo C,Contas1>>backup_nb.txt
XCOPY C:\Contas1 %UNID%\BACKUP\Contas1 /D /V /E /Y
date /T>>backup_nb.txt
time /T>>backup_nb.txt
date /T
time /T
echo **************************************************************
echo     **************************************************************>>backup_nb.txt

echo **************************************************************
echo **************************************************************>>backup_nb.txt
echo C,Contas2
echo C,Contas2>>backup_nb.txt
XCOPY C:\Contas2 %UNID%\BACKUP\Contas2 /D /V /E /Y
date /T>>backup_nb.txt
time /T>>backup_nb.txt
date /T
time /T
echo **************************************************************
echo **************************************************************>>backup_nb.txt

echo. >>backup_nb.txt
echo ### FINAL ####>>backup_nb.txt
date /T>>backup_nb.txt
time /T>>backup_nb.txt
echo.
date /T
echo.
time /T

echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                 * * * * *  F I M  D O  B A C K U P  * * * * *

echo. >>backup_nb.txt
echo.
echo.
echo.

type backup_nb.txt

echo.
echo.
echo                 * * * * *  F I M  D O  B A C K U P  * * * * *
echo.
echo.
echo.

pause

REM     XCOPY origem destino /OPCAO1 /OPCAO2 ...    XCOPY copia sub-   diretorios tambem
rem
rem     XCOPY origem destino /D /E /V /F
REM
REM     /D  SE NENHUMA DATA ESPECIFICADA, COPIA SO OS MAIS NOVOS QUE O   DESTINO
rem         ou copia so os alterados durante ou apos a data especificada  (/D:m-d-y)
rem
rem     /E  copia pastas e sub-pastas INCLUSIVE as vazias
rem
rem     /V  verifica copia
rem
rem     /Y  nao pergunta se substitui
rem
rem     /F  Exibe copia por completo ao copiar

echo on
```

**1) Problema no arquivo BAT**: ao incluir no backup arquivos baixados da internet, por exemplo, alguns não são copiados, pois surge uma mensagem dizendo que "o nome do arquivo é muito extenso".

No caso do software SD, há a própria unidade externa da Seagate e o software do fabricante atualiza automaticamente os dados das pastas selecionadas anteriormente sempre que há alteração nos dados.

**2) Problema no software de backup SD**: fui surpreendido ao consultar os dados "backupeados" e reparei que as datas e horas dos arquivos não são as datas e horas originais, sendo as datas e horas da realização do backup. O problema é que alguns arquivos são gerenciados justamente pela data e hora que foram atualizados, o que prejudica este tipo de controle. Outro problema é que o software SD "não sobrepõe" os arquivos alterados, pois ele mantém cada versão alterada criando pastas de controle para cada um deles, ou seja, se alterei 5 vezes um arquivo em datas diferentes, ele irá gerar cinco novas pastas de controle, cada uma com a respectiva cópia do arquivo alterado na data; porém os últimos arquivos (os mais recentes - arquivos distintos) podem ser recuperados pelo software. Este fato prejudica uma consulta direta aos dados (na unidade de backup), já que os dados mais recentes, salvos em datas distintas, encontram-se em pastas também distintas prejudicando a análise destes dados.

**Dúvida:**

Diante dos problemas apresentados (lembrando que são soluções distintas e independentes), existe um software de backup que copie arquivos de nomes extensos (que no arquivo BAT não são copiados) e que mantenha a data e hora originais dos arquivos "backupeados" além de manter os dados organizados da forma que se encontravam originalmente, ou seja, sobrepondo os arquivos anteriores pelos atualizados e na mesma estrutura de pastas?

**O objetivo é realizar os backups com uma opção que não apresente nenhum destes problemas.**

Grato desde já.

Answer (score 1):

Se o SO é Windows faz o teste utilizando o Cobian Backup.

Utilizo ele a muito tempo e ele tem ótimas opções de backup, além de ser gratuito.

http://cobiansoft.com/

Comment: Oi Laércio, obrigado pela resposta, aguardei para ver se alguém apresentava algo sobre os problemas relatados além de uma indicação para a solução do problema, mas a sua indicação é muito boa, por isso votei na resposta. Grato.

Comment: Obrigado pelo voto @Leo, o backup por batch é muito útil, mas em alguns casos pode te deixar sem opção. Com o Cobian você poderá gerenciar melhor os backups, configurar quando irá apagar os backups antigos e também até enviar e-mail em caso de falha.

Comment: Muito bom. Grato

Comment: Oi @Laércio, fiz alguns testes com o Cobian Backup, que funciona com o Windows 10 apesar de não indicar isso, e reparei um problema (para mim, pelo menos), quando um arquivo ou uma pasta com ou sem arquivos é excluída da origem, na opção "diferencial" (passei a usar esta após o backup na opção "completo"), ele não exclui estes itens do backup, ou seja, se precisar recuperar o backup algum dia ele virá com todos os arquivos e pastas que eu já havia excluído.

Comment: Eu também verifiquei que o backup diferencial está recopiando os mesmos arquivos, e não somente os alterados conforme o software indica...